Book about Female Monster Hunter Protagonist that has fangs
I read this book about a young woman who begins to see monsters that humans can't see and she eventually becomes a monster hunter. Unlike normal monster hunters, the protagonist isn't human and uses her fangs to kill the monsters. I remember a very specific scene in which the protagonist finds a "mentor" to teach her how to kill monsters, and when the mentor tells her she has retractable fangs, the protagonist doesn't believe it because she thought she was human. So the mentor "attacks" her, to scare enough to use her fangs on instinct, which works and the mentor gets her to bite into an apple. The mentor explains to the protagonist that the venom in the fangs is the only thing that kills monsters and explains that the venom tastes sweet to offset the bad taste of monsters. I believe this is a young adult/teen book, I read it in middle school in the early 2010s. It was published with physical copies.
This is everything I can remember about this book but I hope this is enough specific details that someone will know it. Thank you.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

I believe its the Sweet Venom series (2011-2013) by Tera Lynn Childs. Your post helped me remember details which I could then tracked down as I loved this book.
The dust jacket description from the hardcover edition reads:

GRACE just moved to San Francisco and is excited to start over at a new school. The change is full of fresh possibilities, but it's also a tiny bit scary. It gets scarier when a minotaur walks in the door. And even more shocking when a girl who looks just like her
shows up to fight the monster.
GRETCHEN is tired of monsters pulling her out into the wee hours, especially on a school night, but what can she do? Sending the minotaur back to his bleak home is just another notch on her combat belt. She never expected to run into this girl who could be her double, though.
GREER has her life pretty well put together, thank you very much. But that all tilts sideways when two girls who look eerily like her appear on her doorstep and claim they're triplets, supernatural descendants of some hideous creature from Greek myth, destined to spend their lives hunting monsters.
These three teenage descendants of Medusa, the once-beautiful Gorgon maligned in myth, must reunite and embrace their fates in this unique paranormal world where monsters lurk in plain sight.

And the scene where Gretchen uses an apple to teach Grace how to use her fangs:

"Here, take this," I say, handing her the apple. "And close
your eyes."
I think back to Ursula's earliest lessons. It's been four years since she found me and we started training, but I remember every session as if it were only yesterday. When you've spent a lifetime feeling like a worthless burden, you tend to pay attention to the person who gives you a destiny.
Grace closes her eyes.
"Now," I say, circling around her as I speak, "think about the monster that attacked you at the bus stop. Picture every slimy, snaky detail."
Her brow creases and her upper lip curls in disgust. Good girl.
"Imagine it has you pinned down. You're trapped." I step close and whisper, "You're scared and helpless and angry."
She starts shaking all over, and I have a feeling I'm getting it pretty close to what actually happened. I’m not trying to freak her out, but she has to learn to overcome the fear. I wouldn't be good at my job if I went out hunting terrified of what might happen.
To her credit, she doesn't open her eyes or beg me to stop.
"You think you're about to die," I say, making my voice as low and hypnotic as possible. "Now"—I stop in front of Grace—"picture yourself flipping it over, so you’re on top and it's trapped beneath you. You're in control."
Her lips spread into a small smile. Two perfectly white fangs slide into place so smoothly, she doesn't notice.
"Now, pretend the apple is the beast's neck," I command. "Bite!"

The bit about the venom tasting sweet:

"Can I—?" She reaches out and gingerly touches the apple, collecting some of the venom on her fingertip.
"It's harmless to us," I explain. "Taste it. It's kind of sweet,
actually."
I don't mention that it's probably sweet in order to cut the nasty taste of monster. She doesn’t need to know that yet.


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe this work and explain how it matches the question?

Huh. I'd come upon this one in my search, but didn't see the mention of the fangs.

^_^ Given someone edited my quotes into the answer, I'll yield.
